# Jetty started twice

Tags: jetty, guice

A weird case is happening in my application, some code that is in a Guice EagerSingleton is being run twice. I printed a stack trace (Below) and it shows that the public static main of jetty is being called twice. Where could I have miss-configured it?

```
//Stack trace (Is printing in logs twice)
at com.ea.wsop.GraphiteReporterConfig.<init>(GraphiteReporterConfig.java:50)
at com.ea.wsop.GraphiteReporterConfig$$FastClassByGuice$$22005e5b.newInstance(<generated>)
at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
...
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:477)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:623)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.parseCommandLine(Main.java:273)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:81)
```

I am running Jetty 7.2.2 & Guice Version 3.0, Please comment on which other config files would be useful to post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you can use *either* the webapp provider or the context provider but not both in this case

I am a fan of just using contexts personally, more nimble.

just remove the jetty-webapps.xml line in your start.ini

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out,

I was setting up the web app in /home/j2play/j2play/jetty/contexts/app.xml and it was in the standard Jetty/webapps directory so jetty was scanning and starting it automatically too. I moved my war outside the standard location and it works fine.